# Display header files in Qt Creator using Cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

So I just setup a new Cmake project with Qt Creator. Then I added some classes to the project and Qt Creator is displaying the files as follows:

- Project Folder

  - Project Name

    - Source files
  - Header Files

Now when I add a header file (New File > C++ Header File) only (**without** a source file), the header file is not displayed in the project tree that Qt Creator shows (I can't find it under Header Files). I can see that the header file is being created (using Ctrl+K) but it is not showing under Header Files.
I have read another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298302/cmake-qtcreator-and-header-files) but the main answer provided doesn't really answer the question.

My `CMakeslist.txt` looks as the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TEST LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# QtCreator supports the following variables for Android, which are identical to qmake Android variables.
# Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html for more information.
# They need to be set before the find_package(Qt5 ...) call.

#if(ANDROID)
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
#    if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
#        set(ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libcrypto.so
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libssl.so)
#    endif()
#endif()


find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)

if(ANDROID)
    add_library(TEST SHARED
      main.cpp
      wetcanvas.cpp
      wetrenderer.cpp
      qml.qrc
    )
else()
    add_executable(TEST
      main.cpp
      wetcanvas.cpp
      wetrenderer.cpp
      qml.qrc
    )
endif()

target_compile_definitions(TEST
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(TEST
  PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick)
```

Comment: Is this a build under control of QtCreater, or one under control by CMake? Two different matters entirely...

Comment: If your question is actually the **same** as the other earlier question, you should add a *bounty* to that question, instead of asking the same question again in a different post. The bounty will draw better answers for the earlier question, and won't duplicate content.

Comment: @squareskittles the questions are somewhat related but they arent' the same. In my case, the header and source files are nicely visually separated in QtCreator, it's only when a header file without a source file is created that it is not shown.

Comment: @DevSolar the project has been created directly with Qt Creator and uses CMake as its build system.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a basic example CMakeLists.txt as created by QtCreator. I have some knowledge of CMake, but no QtCreator at hand. Show a header that "works" and one that doesn't, and let us see what is different...

Comment: @DevSolar ok I have added my CMakeLists.txt file

Comment: Well, it appears that QtCreator is not adding headers (either those displayed or those not displayed) to CMakeLists.txt; that means CMake can't do anything about making QtCreator display it. Header files would have to be listed together with the source files in `add_library()` / `add_executable()`. Don't worry, CMake knows not to *compile* them, but it needs to *know* about them in some way. Then you can put them into a `source_group()`... at which point you are where that other question left off, with QtCreator apparently being fuzzy with *any* kind of header files...

Comment: @DevSolar yes, it's very strange. However, it does display the header files if they have the corresponding source file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the header to the sources list in CMake.
In your case

```
if(ANDROID)
    add_library(TEST SHARED
      main.cpp
      wetcanvas.cpp
      wetrenderer.cpp
      MyHeader.h
      qml.qrc
    )
else()
    add_executable(TEST
      main.cpp
      wetcanvas.cpp
      wetrenderer.cpp
      MyHeader.h
      qml.qrc
    )
endif()
```

Tip:
You might want to consider to put your sources in their own variable like so:

```
      set(COMMON_SRC
          main.cpp
          wetcanvas.cpp
          wetrenderer.cpp
          MyHeader.h
          qml.qrc
      )
      set(ANDROID_SRC
          AndroidSpecific.cpp
          AndroidSpecific.h
      )

      if(ANDROID)
        add_library(TEST SHARED
          ${COMMON_SRC}
          ${ANDROID_SRC}
        )   
    else()
        add_executable(TEST
         ${COMMON_SRC}
        )
    endif()
```

It pays off when the project gets more complex.

Comment: I see, I wonder however why is Qt Creator recognizing header files that have an associated source file but with single header files they are required to be manually added.

Comment: QtCreator never was very good with CMake, at least in my experience, though in recent versions its much better than it was. I personally do not use QtCreator's CMake features, I do my CMakeLists.txt by my self so I can't say exactly if and what magic QtCreator is doing to know these headers you add as part of the class. Maybe its the fact they are included that tips QtCreator about them.

Comment: I have opened a bug for Qt Creator about this: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-28289